# android - How to put the determinate progress bar

Tags: android

In my application I want to display the progress bar 1000msec. I am using the following code but the progress bar is converted to indeterminate mode. How to handle it?

My Code is as follows,

```
Exitexpand_pd = ProgressDialog.show(RB_UpcomingExits.this, "", "Please wait...", true);
Thread t = new Thread() 
{
   public void run() 
   {
     try 
     {                                                                                                                                             
     setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);
     Thread.sleep(1000);                                                  
      if(Exitexpand_pd.isIndeterminate())                                                   
         Exitexpand_pd.dismiss();                                                                                                                           
     } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {                                                    
      e.printStackTrace();
     }                                                              
    rb_Exitexpand_Handler.post(null);                                             
    Exitexpand_pd.dismiss();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the doc for the [show](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html) method. You have to change the boolean to false.

```
Exitexpand_pd = ProgressDialog.show(RB_UpcomingExits.this, "", "Please wait...", false);
```

Comment: ya i am putting the false till it is showing indeterminate. is any problem when i am using the  rb_Exitexpand_Handler.post(null);                                             
    Exitexpand_pd.dismiss();

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly set that you don't want indeterminate progress in your dialog:

```
pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
pd.setIndeterminate(false);
```

Comment: i am doing like this till not working(means convert inderterminate)

Comment: side comment: @naresh you're saying "till" but from context I believe you mean "still", I was misreading it for your other comment until I read this comment.